# Upgrading flycheck when installed systemwide

Tags: flycheck

I'm trying to upgrade my system-wide installation of flycheck from v31 to v32, but couldn't figure out a way to do it. `m-x package-list-packages U x` doesn't work, there are no packages to upgrade.

I'm using CentOS 8, should I just delete the package from `/usr/share` and try to install it from Melpa? dnf doesn't seem to have a flycheck package either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Which version of Emacs? `Menu Bar -> Help -> About Emacs`
2. `Menu Bar -> Options -> Manage Emacs Packages`?
3. You will see a list of Packages.  Can you see `flycheck` in that buffer?
4. If yes, it is a good idea to do `Menu Bar -> Package -> Refresh Package List`.
5. Then go to line that says `flycheck`, `Menu Bar -> Package -> Mark for Install`
6. Then do, `Menu Bar -> Package -> Executed Marked Actions`.
7. Restart `Emacs`.

---

If you don't see `flycheck`, then `Menu Bar -> Package -> Customize`, go to the line that says `Package Archives` and configure it as below.  Note that `flycheck` is available in `MELPA`, and you need to have it in your `package-archives`.  Use the `Apply and Save Button`  Then repeat the previous steps.  You will see `flycheck` in list of available packages.

[image: M-x customize-variable RET package-archives RET]

Comment: Ah, turns out I can just install the newer version from `packages-list-packages` instead of trying to upgrade the system package. So what I did is `M-x package-list-packages Enter`, search for `flycheck` then`i x` and it installed the correct emacs version. Thank you!